# Is there a way to enforce default values in NewtonSoft json models?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stylecop

I have this schema for one of my DB documents:

```
public class InfoDoc
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "documentId", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string documentId {get; set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "creatorId", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string creatorId{get; set;}
}
```

I have been using it for my application for a while now. I added a new property called `creationTime` but forgot to set `DefaultValue` attribute for it.

I also made the mistake of referencing the `creationTime` without initializing it. Not all the existing documents in the DB have that field populated. So I ran into null reference exceptions when using the web app.

Is there any Stylecop/code analyzer rule that I can leverage to ensure that such properties  always have a default value and null value handling attributes set?

Comment: Currently there doesn't seem to be a way to set this as a default rule, you have to set this rule per data. If anyone knows how to set it up, please answer this question.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT what do you mean by "you have to set this rule per data"?